Possible way of lowering stats while not in the app
I've recently started learning flutter for school and now it's time for the final project - I decided to do something similar to Pou. I have my different rooms responsible for eating, cleaning, etc. And here comes my problem: in the original Pou there were stats that lowered over time. When you came back to your game after 8 hours your Pou would be hungry, etc. I'm trying to implement that into my own game.
I don't want any code solutions, just an idea of how that would even be implemented. I was thinking maybe it was possible to store the app-closing time, and calculate the new hunger stat- when the app opens again, taking the app-opening time and doing something with that. I'm using flame and plan to add hive, because that's what we did before. Is there a better way to do this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think you have the right idea for solving that.  Storing the time the user left the app and comparing it to the time they reopened it should be the most effective way.  It allows you to get around the app idling or closing entirely.  The same idea is how a lot of websites handle timeouts.  For example, when you don't have the browser window loaded, JavaScript can't keep counting for the comparison.
It is also doesn't need to just be limited to the user leaving the app.  If the "Pou" can get hungry while you are playing, you can just save the last time it was fed or the last time its hunger reached a certain level and compare against that. I have never used Flutter so I am unsure how easy it would be to know that the app was closed and save the time without the game idling, but this approach could get around that possible limitation too.
